# ESP32-WROOM-32 and WLED not communicating correctly to WS2812B LED strips

Tags: esp32, led-driver, led-strip, ws2812b

I am trying to follow Youtube tutorials to run WLED (a program) on an ESP32-WROOM-32 board I purchased, to control addressable LED strips (WS2812B).

I bought a board that does not exactly match the tutorials I've found, so I'm having to interpret the information appropriately, but I think I might be failing at this step.

**The problem:**
When I connect power and ESP32-WROOM-32 to the strip, the LEDs light up but does not respond to controls. With the strips length set to 30, 8 LEDs light up, 7 white and last one green. If I increase the length to 300 (60/m * 5m), all the LEDs light up, but they seem to just flicker randomly, as if the pin is just echoing the traffic on the COM port and the LEDs are displaying bits of information.

Every time I send a change to the board the flicker activity increases briefly.

**Setup process:**
I had to download the virtual COM port drivers to get the ESP32 to show up in Win 11, but once I figured that out, I was able to flash the WLED app onto the ESP32.

WiFi is setup, connected and shows up when I run the WLED app on my phone.

The ESP32 is still being powered via the USB micro port, and the LED strip is being run off a 5 V PSU via two extra included power injection wires on the strip.

Only the data line is hooked up to the ESP32, currently it's set up to communicate via pin 16, but I also tried it on pin 2 and got the same results (once WLED was updated with the matching pin).

Here is the [LED strip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0956C7KFR) that I'm using, and this is the [ESP32-WROOM-32](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09J95SMG7)

**Photos of the setup:**
My ESP32-WROOM-32
https://photos.app.goo.gl/fhgxVe7dYariZrLh7
2102 chip I used to ID the driver
https://photos.app.goo.gl/oW256YpDvMkrzt1K6
How it's wired
https://photos.app.goo.gl/utnvGa2UMFpCBtFC7
A photo of jump lead on pin 16, showing the pinout on bottom of board
https://photos.app.goo.gl/NZtb3RS9PfuXDZUs5
Really it's on pin 16, right? Am I doing this right?
https://photos.app.goo.gl/HTNPdqBUXvL9ysm46
8 Lit up LEDs (Length set to 30)
https://photos.app.goo.gl/NJnCC7Wm8yVNvMMw5
Short video of me turning the lights on and off in WLED android, and the lights flickering.
[Video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/KUPTCR2kXGphKbpB7)

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Is a "wiled" and your LED strip the same thing? (What is a "wiled?")

Comment: Capitalise brand names and proper nouns correctly to make it clear. e.g., USB, ESP32, WiFi, Wroom / WROOM?, 'V' for volt, Win11. It may seem picky but it makes a big difference to legibility, clarity and professionalism.

Comment: Would this be a sentence of it's own: *with the led length set to 30, 8 leds light up, 7 white last one green* ?

Comment: @MiNiMe Quick tip: always expand "it's" to "it is" as a check to see if you've used the correct one (its vs it's).

Comment: @JYelton And here I am figuring if I should take a shot at editing the question :)

Comment: @MiNiMe I still appreciate the assistance in editing!

Comment: Please upload the images using the image uploader so that they are visible *within* the post. Fewer people will bother to click links to view the images. Also, when the external image links die, your post will not be as understandable without the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no ground connection between your strip and your microcontroller and thus no circuit connecting them. Add a return path for current back to the microcontroller ground.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.